# application suspension and running background thread on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I need to run processing in background thread which can take on average 30-150 seconds. This is triggered by user. The process require to do some network communication and file processing in isolated storage.
Is there any detailed description how windows phone handles processes / sockets handles / file handles when application is suspended / thombstoned?

I cannot use background tasks due to memory constraints.

My specific questions:

1. What exactly happens to threads and resources (files/sockets-network/memory, managed and unmanaged) when user for instance press back / lock screen / home / incoming call?
2. What should I expect when application is resumed - an exception on socket which is no longer valid?
3. How to find out if exception was caused by network issue or because of closed connection after thombstoning?

UPDATE:
I cannot use ResourceIntensiveTask due to constraints like memory / connecting to power supply / low-spec phones ...

Comment: The only thing i can recommend so far is http://community.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2012/04/08/what-happens-to-network-calls-when-your-wp7-app-goes-dormant.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The only solution, that could fit to your requirements, is using **ResourceIntensiveTask**, as it's described here:
[Background agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
and here
[ResourceIntensiveTask Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.resourceintensivetask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: The requirement from my question - I CANNOT use tasks.

Comment: To your question, when your app is paused, no communication or computation is done. Also default periodic task has memory limit only 11MB, but ResourceIntensiveTask has much higher memory and duration limit and could be probably used for this purpose.